# Triggering form_errors(form)

Tags: forms, symfony-2.1

I am working on my first Symfony2 project and have just started with form templating. I couldn't find any information on what `form_errors(form)` outputs. From what I could find it is supposed to output global form errors not related to the fields. What does that imply and how can I trigger them for templating purposes?